# Directive template not evaluating expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started playing with AngularJS today and am stuck. Pardon the coffeescript and haml.

```
# some-js-file.js.coffee
app.directive "sr", ->
  restrict: "C"
  replace: true
  transclude: true
  scope:
    serviceRequest: "@servReq"
  template: "<div>" + "<div class=\"name\">{{service_request}}</div>" + "<div class=\"body\" ng-transclude></div>" + "</div>"
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    scope.$watch 'serviceRequest', (serviceRequest) ->
      console.log scope.serviceRequest, serviceRequest
    # cool stuff

# index.html.haml
# more cool stuff...
.row{'ng-repeat' => 'service_request in service_requests'}
  .sr{'serv-req' => '{{service_request}}'}
    {{service_request.description}}
```

The loop and basic template are displaying except that the {{service_request}} expression isn't being evaluated - just blank.

You will notice that in the 'link:' section, I had to $watch the scope for the console.log to work - it wasn't evaluating serviceRequest either. What's going on?

Thanks!!

Comment: I just want to add that it does not evaluate service_request because you created an isolate scope and did not pass it through. The answer by Brandon is actually more complete though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `service_request` is an object (as indicated by `service_request.description` on the last line), then you cannot pass it into the directive using interpolation (`{{service_request}}`) and attribute-based binding (`@servReq`).

Instead, you want the *actual* JavaScript value to be passed through, so you'll need to change your Haml to

```haml
.sr{'serv-req' => 'service_request'}
```

and upate your directive to use bi-directional binding based on the attribute

```coffeescript
scope:
  service_request: "=servReq"
```

(You also need to underscore `service_request` here, because that's how it's used in the template.)

It's hard to really tell what you're trying to do, but here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/Z7Bru/

Comment: Perfect. I completely misunderstood what Angular was doing with the variables. You hit it on the head. Thanks so much for your help.